# Is the weak-* topology on a topological vector space Hausdorff?

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, topological-vector-spaces, separation-axioms

Let $V$ be a topological vector space and $V^*$ be the space of linear functionals induced with the weak-* topology. Can we say that $V^*$ is Hausdorff? Here is my attempt:

Let $\lambda\ne\lambda'\in V^*$. Then, there exists $v\in V$ such that $\lambda(v)\ne\lambda'(v)$. Choose $|\lambda(v)-\lambda'(v)|/2>\epsilon>0$. Then, the open sets 
$$\{\psi\in V^*: \|\psi-\lambda\|_v<\epsilon\}\qquad \{\psi\in V^*:\|\psi-\lambda'\|_v<\epsilon\}$$
are disjoint. So, every distinct point can be seperated by disjoint open sets, thus $V^*$ is Hausdorff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is indeed correct. You might want to expand on why these (basic) open sets are indeed disjoint (triangle inequality argument).

Abstractly, this argument works because the point-evaluations $e_v$, where $v \in V$, form a family of functions (to a Hausdorff space, namely the underlying field) that separates points, in this case basically by definition (different functionals are distinct functions so must be different for some point of the domain), while for the weak topology on $V$ we need some assumption on $V$ to ensure that all linear functionals can separate points, but then also the weak topology is Hausdorff.

Comment: So, I used the fact that the topological scalar field $K$ is Hausdorff.

Comment: @E.Girgin because the norm of distinct points is positive. So you use it implicitly.

Comment: Does the OP's proof here assume that open balls are always weak-* open?

Comment: @VeryForgetfulFunctor  no it doesn’t.

Comment: Hmm... how is it then guaranteed that these open balls are weak-* open in this case if weak-* topology is strictly coarser than norm topology?

Comment: @VeryForgetfulFunctor it uses the basic open subsets of the weak star topology, these are open by definition. You misunderstand them as open balls.

Comment: Note that $\{\psi\in V^\ast \mid \|\phi - \lambda \|_v < \varepsilon\}=\{\psi\in V^\ast \mid | \phi(v) - \lambda(v)| < \varepsilon\}$... @VeryForgetfulFunctor